# Java client for XtreemFS

Tags: java, distributed-computing, distributed-filesystem

I am building a Java web application which will require storing and retrieving large files. I would like to be able to scale the application for the future so I was planning on using XtreemFS http://www.xtreemfs.org/ as a distributed file system. It provides the redundancy and speed I need.

I'm hoping to find a direct client for it for Java but having a little bit of trouble finding one. There are some advanced features of XtreemFS which allow controlling the level of redundancy and by making files read-only can reduce locking overhead.

If I cannot find a Java client, then I will just mount the XtreemFS data store on my servers, treat it just like I would local storage, and use basic java.io.* classes to read and write files from it as if it were just files on the disk.

Any suggestions on the best practices for using XtreemFS?

Comment: XtreemFS does not run on HDFS, but you can run MapReduce jobs on XtreemFS as a FileSystem. So your question is kinda obsolete I think...

Comment: Having said that, since it is actually mounted into your webserver, you can use the Java FileSystem Api- why would you need a library for that?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the HDFS part. The Java filesystem api will probably do the trick. However, the reason I was looking for a direct API was so that the application could configure the connection, as well as use some of the advanced features of XtreemFS. There are some read/write modes and replication modes configurable in XtreemFS that make it more efficient. I was hoping to take advantage of those by using a Java client.

Comment: I revised the question after your clarification about HDFS.

Comment: I would rather just use it as a file system. I am in the process of evaluating XtreemFS to replace a NFS mount. I'vent read the docs fully, but the metadata server seems to be a SPOF with just a backup and no transparent failover. Would be interested in knowing if its not the case.